# White background to transparent background using PIL python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can i transform all white background  and white elements of a png or jpg image in a transparent backgroun using PIL?

Answer (score 9):

Using numpy, the following makes white-ish areas transparent. You can change `threshold` and `dist` to control the definition of "white-ish".

```
import Image
import numpy as np

threshold=100
dist=5
img=Image.open(FNAME).convert('RGBA')
# np.asarray(img) is read only. Wrap it in np.array to make it modifiable.
arr=np.array(np.asarray(img))
r,g,b,a=np.rollaxis(arr,axis=-1)    
mask=((r>threshold)
      & (g>threshold)
      & (b>threshold)
      & (np.abs(r-g)<dist)
      & (np.abs(r-b)<dist)
      & (np.abs(g-b)<dist)
      )
arr[mask,3]=0
img=Image.fromarray(arr,mode='RGBA')
img.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

The code is easy to modify so that only RGB value (255,255,255) is turned transparent -- if that is what you truly want. Simply change the `mask` to:

```
mask=((r==255)&(g==255)&(b==255)).T
```

Comment: I understand threshold, but can you explain the purpose of distance here?

Comment: @kangax: By lowering the `dist` you can ensure that you eliminate only grayish colors.

Comment: Ahh... makes sense! #000, #555, #aaa, ccc, #eee, #fff are all shades of grey (distance = 0) so the less distance the grey-er colors are. Thanks.