# Using machine learning to remove background in image of hand-written signature

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am new to machine learning.
I want to prepare a document with a signature at the bottom of it.
For this purpose I am taking a photo of the user's signature for placement in the document.

How can I using machine learning extract only the signature part from the image and place it on the document?
Input example:
[image: Input]

Output expected in gif format:
[image: Output]

Comment: IMO, machine learning is irrelevant/overkill for this task.

Comment: The "expected output" image tells nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the green image plane. Then take the complementary of the gray value of every pixel as the transparency coefficient. Then you can perform compositing to the destination.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Answer (score 1):

A simple image-processing technique using OpenCV should work. The idea is to obtain a binary image then bitwise-and the image to remove the non-signature details. Here's the results:

Input image

[image]

Binary image

[image]

Result

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Bitwise-and and color background white
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=thresh)
result[thresh==0] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score -2):

Please do research before posting questions like these. A simple google search of "extract signature from image python" gave so many results.

1. [Git Repo](https://github.com/ahmetozlu/signature_extractor)
2. [Git Repo](https://github.com/vzat/signature_extractor)
3. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999072/how-to-extract-signature-from-an-image-python-script)

There are many other such alternatives. Please have a look and try a few approaches.

If you still have some questions or doubts, then post the approach you have taken and a discussion is warranted.